# Kак написать vbscript по этой схеме?

Tags: vbscript, xlsx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как написать vbscript по этой схеме?

Comment: Может VBA, а не VBScript?

Comment: главное чтобы водил сравнил и выдал или по такому принципу Dim Input Input = InputBox("Enter your name")  MsgBox ("You entered: " & Input)

Comment: выводить даже можно на set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") speech.speak

Comment: хочу сделать базу данных для чат бота

Comment: база данных есть но надо вбскрипт чтобы быстро сравнил фразу и ответил

Comment: есть такой вариант vbscript файл запускается голосом как вопрос Dim computerName
computerName=Array("ответ1","ответ2","ответ3","ответ4","ответ5","ответ6")
set speech = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") 
Randomize
speech.speak computerName(Int(Rnd*6))